# how to replace continuous pattern in text

Tags: regex, sed

i have text like **1|2|3|||** , and try to replace each **||** with **|0|**,  my command is following

```
      echo  '1|2|3|||'  | sed -e 's/||/|0|/g'
```

but get result  **1|2|3|0||**,  the pattern is only replaced once.

could someone help me improve the command,  thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/||/|0|/g;s//[0]/g' file
```

or:

```
sed ':a;s/||/|0|/g;ta' file
```

The replacement needs to actioned twice because part of the match is in the replacement.

Comment: thx; the second way extended my knowledge

Answer (score 3):

Just do it 2 times

```
l_replace='s#||#|0|#g'
echo  '1|2|3||||||||4||5|||'  | sed -e "$l_replace;$l_replace"
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Using any sed or any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ echo  '1|2|3|||'  | sed -e 's/||/|0|/g; s/||/|0|/g'
1|2|3|0|0|

$ echo  '1|2|3|||'  | awk '{while(gsub(/\|\|/,"|0|"));}1'
1|2|3|0|0|
```